# WebSocket Safari iPad goes to readystate 3 immediately

Tags: javascript, ios, ipad, safari, websocket

I've got a situation where every other browser/device combination works as expected but on Mobile Safari (iPad), when I attempt to use WebSockets to connect to a custom WebSocket Server, the browser end immediately get's set to readystate: 3.

```
try {
    network.var.ws = new WebSocket('wss://hostname:port');
} catch (ex) {
    console.log('WEB SOCKET FAILURE');
    console.log(ex);
}
```

The specific error I get in Safari Web Inspector is:

```
WebSocket network error: The operation couldn’t be completed. (OSStatus error -9807.)
```

I get the object returned as a WebSocket object but the readystate property is always 3 (CLOSED), ONLY in Safari on the iPad's that I've tested.

I have tested this in Safari on a Mac Book Pro (the only other mac device I have available) and it works perfectly first go!

Googling the error message yielded no results so any help would be most appreciated.

Comment: Did you get anywhere with this? It looks like I've stumbled across the same issue today.